# How to create Rave/Strobe (Colour changing, flashing) lights in a Cycles animation

Tags: animation, light

I'd like to have a "Rave/strobe" lighting effect, lots of various point lights all around the scene while the animation goes on, all rapidly changing colour in random patterns.

Is there any way to do this?

I do only have a short amount of time to finish this, so a easily understood and beginner level explanation would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4):

### F-Curves modifier

Use nodes for your lights.

Add a HSV (far) **Color ramp** to feed the **Emission shader** color.

Now you just have to keframe the Factor of the color ramp and the Strenght of the emission node to a starting value.

Open the Graph editor and add a Noise modifier to each of the keframed channels and adjust the parameters to suit you needs. Factor should bounce between 0 and 1, while for the strenght you can go wild.

[image]

You can even use/combine others modifiers (sine, stepped interpolation....) to achieve other results.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much :)